# JSON creation in objective c, invalid JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am creating a `JSON` to be sent in service on checking online its showing error:

> Error: Parse error on line 1:
>       [{\ "SAHExpertCode\"
>       --^ Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
>       My JSON is [{\"SAHExpertCode\" : \"\",    \"ShiftType\" : \"AM\", \"LocFunId\" : \"CLT0004218\", \"SAHQualCode\" : \"CA\"  }]
>   Please tell me what's wrong and how to correct it.First i am making JSON filterString = [{ "SAHExpertCode" : "", "ShiftType" : "AM", "LocFunId" : "CLT0004218","SAHQualCode" : "CA" }] on checking found it is correct then creating a dictionary NSDictionary*dictData=@{@"MbrId":[USER_DEFAULTS valueForKey:@"MemberId"],@"StrFilter":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",filterString],@"shiftCrtlNos":shftCntrlNmbrs}; NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; [finalArray addObject:dictData]; NSString *finalString =[self ConvertArrayToJsonData:finalArray];finalString = [finalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]; finalString = [finalString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];after creation of final string it is generating symbol \ for JSON Conversion my code is -(NSString *)ConvertArrayToJsonData:(NSMutableArray *)array{ NSError *error;
>        NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error]; NSString *JSONString; if (!jsonData) { NSLog(@"error :%@",error); } else {JSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // NSLog(@"jsonstring:%@",JSONString);
>        }
>        return JSONString;
>   }
>   //i need JSON like [  {    "StrFilter" : "[  {    \"SAHExpertCode\" : \"\",    \"ShiftType\" : \"PM\",    \"LocFunId\" : \"CLT0004218\",    \"SAHQualCode\" : \"CA\"  }]",    "MbrId" : "MBR0000035",    "shiftCrtlNos" : "0080013526,0080014697"  }] also tell me how to remove \ from String

Comment: can you post some code how you are generating request & JSON also so we can help you out ?

Comment: Tell me exactly how you want to make JSON (Json Format). Give one sample.

Comment: question text is being messed up sorry for that

Comment: Better figure out how to fix this.

Comment: @gnasher729 thank you for your suggestion sir, i figured out the solution by doing
 finalString = [finalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i replaced the unwanted \ symbols by doing 
finalString = [finalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\" withString:@""]; in the JSON string.

Comment: That's going to create total rubbish if the backslashes are actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go to www.json.org and look at the correct formatting of JSON data. And the easiest way to get correctly formatted JSON is to create an array or dictionary that you want to convert to JSON, and use NSJSONSerialization to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Just use default NSJSONSerialization method of iOS

in below example i have a "postMenuArray" which I'm converting in JSON.

```
NSData * postMenuSerial = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postMenuArray options:0 error:nil];

NSString *Menujson = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[postMenuSerial bytes] length:[postMenuSerial length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Here I got JSON response

```
Menujson = [Menujson stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "withString:@""];
```

Lastly I remove all the spacing .

Still facing issue try this

```
Menujson = [Menujson stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```